# How to config PHP libxml path after updated libxml from 2.2.26 to 2.9

Tags: apache-2.2, php, nginx, php-fpm

our servers need to update the libxml2 version from 2.2.26 to 2.9 (latest version). It is no problem that we have been installed the libxml2-2.9 version on our servers. but the problem is how can we config the libs path of libxml2 path in php? Since it still show the old version on phpinfo().

What we have do is
1. [Install libxml2 2.7.X on CentOS 5.X](https://serverfault.com/questions/266927/install-libxml2-2-7-x-on-centos-5-x)

Using yum to install local files, and typed `yum info libxml2`, it shows 2.9 was installed.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: yes, one of the server is using nginx, I have tried restart the apache, nginx, php-fpm or even reboot the server. It still shows old version in phpinfo().

Comment: Where does the PATH environment variable point to for startup in your webserver?  Remember your path may not be the same as system startup.

Comment: @mdpc, I execute `echo $PATH`, it shows 
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/root/bin`. And my libxml2 path is in `/usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 libxml2.so.2.9.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to recompile PHP against the new libxml.

Comment: Yes... that was my findings yesterday. Thank you man!