# libxml2 on CentOS 5.9

Tags: php, centos, yum, library, bug

I'm having problems with a CentOS 5.9 web server running php sites. Apparently `libxml2 2.6.26-2.1.21.el5_9.2` has [a known bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=877348), but there doesn't seem like they've put the newer release into the repo's, as you can't update it using yum.

I searched a lot on this, and also found a few other posts here on Serverfault, but it hasn't worked. I tried Chad's solution [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/266927/install-libxml2-2-7-x-on-centos-5-x) but failed at the last stage. When I tried to do the `yum localinstall`, it gives me this:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/share/man/man1/xmlcatalog.1.gz from install of libxml2-2.7.8-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.21.el5_9.2.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/xmllint.1.gz from install of libxml2-2.7.8-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.21.el5_9.2.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/xmlcatalog.1.gz from install of libxml2-2.7.8-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libxml2-2.6.22-1.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/xmllint.1.gz from install of libxml2-2.7.8-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libxml2-2.6.22-1.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man3/libxml.3.gz from install of libxml2-2.7.8-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libxml2-2.6.22-1.i386
```

So, I thought that perhaps I could `--force` this, but I don't want to do it if it might overwrite something that the system needs, and cause more errors down the line.

On the bug report, Daniel Veillard says there is a fix:

> "A single upstream commit seems to fix the problem"

That sentence makes no sense to me whatsoever, and the link he posted did not clarify in the slightest.

I would appreciate any help with this. I see that it's complaining about files from the 32-bit packages, which I find strange since I'm trying to install 64-bit packages. I would think it would leave the 32-bit ones alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have both the 32-bit and 64-bit packages on your system now, so in order to update them you must update them both at the same time with the same `yum localinstall` invocation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't know if you know any more about this specific package, but the link I downloaded was named: "libxml2-2.8.0-1.src.rpm" which don't really let you know whether it's 32-bit or 64-bit. There was however next to it a package called "libxml2-2.8.0-1.x86_64.rpm", so I thought if anything, the one I downloaded would be the 32-bit one. But after running the commands of the guide, I still ended up with the x64 packages in the destination folder.

Comment: Um... `x86_64` is the 64-bit package. `i386` is the 32-bit package. `src` is the source code. Perhaps now you can find the correct packages.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolve this problem with downgrade `libxml2` and reinstalling PHP

```
sudo yum downgrade libxml2 libxml2-devel libxml2-python
sudo yum reinstall php php-xml
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. By doing this, what new version was installed? Or was it the same version as before, but the bug was fixed?

Comment: Yes, it's the same version as before update, but without bugfix.